# A*_search_algorithm implementation in java

Tags: java, search, a-star, breadth-first-search

I tried to implement a **A*_search_algorithm** but in runTime 
the search method retutern null 
i saw that if a curr node has just a one neighbor that already visited its go out from the loop 
which condition I need to add to fix the alg??

```
public Solution search(Searchable s) {

    final StateT start = s.getInitialState();
    final StateT goal = s.getGoalState();

    initPriority(goal);
    start.setCost(0);
    openList.add(start);
    double tempCost;
    while (!(openList.isEmpty())) {
        StateT curr = openList.poll();
        numOfSteps++;

        if (curr.equals(goal))
            return backTrace(curr);

        closedState.add(curr);

        ArrayList<StateT> successors = s.getAllPossibleStates(curr);
        for (StateT stateT : successors) {
        }
        for (StateT successor : successors) {

            tempCost = curr.getCost() + s.dist_between(curr, successor);

            if (closedState.contains(successor))
                continue;

            if (!(openList.contains(successor)))
                openList.add(successor);

            else if (tempCost >= successor.getCost())
                continue;
            successor.setCameFrom(curr);
            successor.setCost(tempCost);
            openList.remove(successor);
            openList.add(successor);
        }// for         
        for (StateT stateT : openList) {
            System.out.println("op:  "+stateT.getState());              
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }
    return null;
}//

public abstract void initPriority(final StateT goal);


public Solution backTrace(StateT current) {

    Solution solution = new Solution();

    while(current != null){

        solution.getPath().add(current);
        current = (StateT) current.getCameFrom();
    }

    return solution;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the implementation looks to me like it should be correct, as in it should find a path if one exists. This is assuming that any methods for which you did not provide the code (such as `getAllPossibleStates()`) are implemented correctly.

The case that you described (where all possible neighbours of a node have already previously been visited) should not require any additional handling. If this causes your `openList` to run empty and results in returning null, this simply means that no path exists. Are you sure that there exists a path from start to goal in the test you did?

As an additional note, this code does not actually implement the A* algorithm, but Dijkstra's algorithm, because you did not include a heuristic that estimates the cost from a node to the goal.

Comment: thank you. there is a path. the heuristic defined in the  open list comperator. I'll check what you offer.

Comment: The problem was is in getAllPossibleStates() thank's!